# How to set serial port to run in PIO mode (not DMA) in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-port, linux-device-driver, dma

I'm using ubuntu and  need my serial port to run extrictly in PIO mode for a high precision reading requirement (highly deterministic parity error detection).
I can not determine if my /dev/stty0 serial port is actually running  in DMA or PIO mode.

I was not able to determine a setserial or stty parameter for knowing this config.

I found the possibility of passing a kernel parameter

setenv defargs '${defargs} fsl_lpuart.nodma=0'

for enabling/disabling DMA but it not clear where should I use that command.

Hardware being tested: 
Integrated serial port of Lenovo v520S con Intel Core i5-7400 Processor 
Port Details: /dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4)

Comment: In general you may not know for sure, b/c it varies from hardware to hardware. One option, custom though, as you notice for the certain driver is to pass kernel command line parameter. Just do it in the boot loader. Another is to try to make generic knob for low-latency more.

Comment: Depending on your purpose and requirements, it would be a time saver to look for existing hardware products and their device drivers, and could you get a performance/quality guarantee? [SerialGear](https://www.serialgear.com/index.cfm)

Comment: 0andriy please expand about the generic knob for low-latency

Comment: I didn’t research in that area, and my understanding is purely an opinion how it may be done. So, full stack, I.e. UART driver -> serial core -> tty (perhaps not needed) -> UAPI (IOCTLs) -> tooling (`setserial`) should be modified, if not yet, to support this mode when you basically disable DMA and maybe enable some other hardware quirks.

Comment: Why not try a different path, and simply test how well your (unspecified) HW detects parity errors for 8 data bits?  Suggest testing first with 7-bit chars + parity, because I was getting unreliable results using 8-bit chars + parity sent by USB-serial converter and received by a PC-mobo UART.

Comment: sawdust thanks again. Hardware spec added. I will try 7bit+1P detection and update the issue accordingly.

Comment: COM ports (default legacy ones) on PC never support DMA.